# In R programming, regarding Looping

Tags: r

```r
library(mgcv)

model1 <- gam(EE ~ te(Load, Gradient, k=4,  bs=c("tp", "tp")), data = dipasEE)
predict(model1)

pd<- data.frame(Load=c(0.5),Gradient=c(15))
predict(model1,newdata=pd)
```

Output:

```r
pd<- data.frame(Load=c(0.5),Gradient=c(15))
> predict(model1,newdata=pd)
       1 
11.08101
```

When we give values for load and gradient individually I may able to get the output.
How to get the output by varying load from 0 to 20 in 0.5 difference and having gradient as constant?

Comment: `pd <- data.frame(Load = seq(0, 20, by = 0.5), Gradient = 15)`?

Comment: Thank you.Got the Output